# Как сделать авторизацию?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, sql

Почему не авторизовываеться, а выводит ошибку?

```html
<?php
include_once "/home/world/html/engine/config.php";
$dataSource = "mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost";
$db = new PDO($dataSource, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
$result = $db->query("SELECT id, login, password FROM `wUsers` WHERE `login`='".$_POST['login']."' LIMIT 1");
$db->null;

$result->fetch();
$password1 = $result->password;
$login1 = $result->login;
$id = $result->id;

 if ($_POST['password'] == $password1)
 {
 setcookie('csgoserv', $password1, time() + 7200);
 header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
 }
 if ($_GET['logout'] == 'YES')
 {
 setcookie('csgoserv',''); 
 header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
 }
 if ($_POST['password'] != $password1 )
 {
 header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/?mode=failed');
 }

?>
```

Может где-то что-то не правильно вывел? Переменные с формы точно выводяться...

Comment: А запрос точно проходит? Может в место '=' написать 'like' в запросе?

Comment: А какая, собственно, ошибка?

Comment: Ошибку я имел ввиду переход на ?mode=failed..

Answer (score 0):

Приминительно для вашего случая (вставтье в скрипт ваш хост, имя БД и т.д.):

```html
<?php 
try
{
 $pdo = new PDO ('mysql:host=ваш хост;dbname=название вашей БД', 'имя пользователя', 'пароль');
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"'); 
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
 $output = 'Невозможно подключиться к серверу баз данных' . $e->getMessage();
 echo $output;
 exit();
}
try
{
 $sql = "SELECT id, login, password FROM `wUsers` WHERE `login`='".$_POST['login']."' LIMIT 1";
 $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
 $output = 'Ошибка при выполнении обновления: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
 echo $output;
 exit();
}

$row = $result->fetch();
$password1 = $row['password'];
$login1 = $row['login'];
$id = $row['id'];

if ($_POST['password'] == $password1)
 {
 setcookie('csgoserv', $password1, time() + 7200);
 header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
 }
 if ($_GET['logout'] == 'YES')
 {
 setcookie('csgoserv',''); 
 header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
 }
 if ($_POST['password'] != $password1 )
 {
 header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/?mode=failed');
 }

?>
```

На будущее, когда используете PDO  для подключения к БД, надо использовать конструкцию try...catch для отлавливания ошибок.